# What does the "count" column mean in an iPhone low memory report?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I'm trying to decrypt a low memory crash log from my iPhone, and I see that the count number for my application is huge (35314). What does this indicate?

```
Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
      MobileMail <bd66c3ae9a91225e745044a8051e5458>     906 (jettisoned)
  MY_APPLICATION <fe63329c069b3b7fb2796eec33669af6>   35314 (jettisoned) (active)
     dataaccessd <cb2dfcefb43430f4550f0187890de64a>     365
            apsd <5aa3f4fcfc53b00dde75378aed8e1af3>     216
             lsd <f711e4c8e9e3fe740bea8de2b98c3f25>     358
         notifyd <f36b987ef3d560324ff7384c1b9e448e>      91
        BTServer <399771bd4f5090d5572ab3c753a01c7f>     136
      CommCenter <86ed1b990c91d8d3ac6533f2400ab973>     219
     SpringBoard <c014cf8d4559f5596a92131934f61166>    6017 (active)
      accessoryd <0e514c4b9547bbb5f153435a91b7b831>     114
         configd <dcdf074c5152eb97309ea55d200d32ad>     402
   fairplayd.K48 <b6aee1a5594de9cadfee552a00f16978>      82
       locationd <f496d6de4951e767807ed191addf19ec>     360
   mDNSResponder <b14bb33d877732ed866786776833f72c>     178
    mediaremoted <ca81c5e8d3b982bca9e1c0f05e203eca>     150
    mediaserverd <b09e22f7c7495c8ee56691c74beac1bd>    1343
       lockdownd <1bb238048747f8407c2ff1cf0d920c42>     222
         syslogd <5532491b0def7a60037a52400c48e715>     102
         launchd <bff2d05de78d5832b2c9604413668f3a>     102

**End**
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a description of what a resident page is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory (specifically under the "Permanently resident pages" title). Basically it is the number of memory pages your process is holding and it really only means that you are using way too much memory (which you already knew ;) ).